# Bootstrap Tab is not working when tab with data-target instead of href

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am developing bootstrap tabs with the use of `data-target` attribute to match the tab panes instead of using the `href` attribute, since i am developing angular app(`href` might spoil my route ).

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="messages">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
 </div>

<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
    })
</script>
```

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/4/. Where i recreated the whole .

I don't want the bootstrap style to be applied for my tabs, i want only the functionality, i want my styles to applied , is it anyway to stop bootstrap style to be applied?
Please help in this thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add `data-toggle="tab"` attribute in your markup

```
<a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/12/)

Comment: Thanks For the Help. Now it is working. One more doubt, whether the data-toggle attributes supported in IE8?

Comment: @MohamedHussain in the twb source code, they're using the jQuery ``attr`` function to read out the ``data-attribute``. This should be supported by most browsers (up until IE6, I think?) and definitely IE8

Comment: Thanks for this solution and saving me from going crazy.

Answer (score 2):

try like this :

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#myTab a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Sachin, you have to specify the `data-toggle` attribute.
Other than that, make sure you correctly fill in your `data-target`s. These take jQuery selectors, **not** element ids, when used with `` `data-target ``.([link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/90fb40b7073af222478a99ee1ef93da879cac8b8/js/tab.js#L33))

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `data-toggle="tab"` - you can remove your js initialization -

```
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
    })
</script>
```

Bootstrap will init tabs automatically.

If you want to init your tabs maually - you can remove `data-toggle="tab"` from the layout and itin all tabs separately:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```