# Bootstrap nav-tabs href is not displaying in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Using simple bootstrap nav-tabs. Onclick of tab anchor href value should append on existing url. But here only I am not able to do that.

Example :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
    <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Home">HOME </a> </li>
    <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Documents">DOCUMENTS </a> </li>
    <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Applications">APPLICATIONS </a> </li>              
</ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - Tabs - URL doesn't change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131273/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-url-doesnt-change)

Comment: Try this http://www.ordinarycoder.com/bootstrap-tabs-change-url-hash-jump/

Answer (score 0):

Add **data-toggle="tab"** attribute in your markup

```
<a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
```

Also you can check here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225968/bootstrap-tab-is-not-working-when-tab-with-data-target-instead-of-href)

Comment: For me tab function is working but href value is not appending in existing url fragment

Comment: Did you check the link I have shared?

Comment: Can you share whole code or fiddle URL that will be more helpful for us?